# Tried getting all iFrames on a page, but ran into ProcessEndedUnexpectedlyException. Tried async function, only parses one iFrame. How can I fix this?

Tags: c#, selenium, recursion, iframe

So I'm in the process of creating a Base iFrame Class to generically parse nested iFrames from any page without utilizing IDs, xpaths or anything DOM specific. With that information in mind, I have two questions:

**Question 1**: While I believe my code logically makes sense, I kept running into ProcessEndedUnexpectedlyException. This is expected since I'm using a static method, but do you have any suggestions to improve my code?

BaseiFrame class:

```
namespace [Confidental namespace] {
 public class BaseIFrame {
         protected IWebDriver _driver;

         private ReadOnlyCollection<IWebElement> _iframes;

 public BaseIFrame(IWebDriver _driver) { 
        this._driver = _driver;     
         
        _iframes = _driver.FindElements(By.TagName("frame"));             
        _iframesSize = _iframes.Count();             
     }

 public ReadOnlyCollection<IWebElement> getFrames() {
            return _iframes;
        }         

private static IEnumerable GetAllFramesRecursive<T>(IWebElement frame, IWebDriver driver)
        {
            var result = new Stack<IWebElement>();
            BaseIFrame baseClass = new BaseIFrame(driver);

            var iFrameList = baseClass._iframes;
            foreach (var i in iFrameList)
            {
                result.Push(i);

                foreach (IWebElement e in GetAllFramesRecursive<IWebElement>(i, driver))
                {
                    result.Push(e);
                }
            }

            return result;
        }

        // Public callable method for unit test
        public void GetAlliFramesRecursivePublic<T>(IWebElement test, IWebDriver driver)
        {
            GetAllFramesRecursive<IWebElement>(test, driver);
        }
    }
}
```

BaseiFrameTests class:

```
        [TestMethod]
        public void AssertiFrameLength()
        {
            Login();

            var expected = 0;

            BaseIFrame bif = new BaseIFrame(_driver);
            bif.GetAlliFramesRecursivePublic<IWebElement>(bif.getFrames()[0], _driver);

            var elementSize = _driver.FindElements(By.TagName("*")).Count;

            for (var i = 0; i < elementSize; i++)
            {
                var iframesSize = _driver.FindElements(By.TagName("frame")).Count;
                expected += iframesSize;
            }

            var actual = bif.getFrames();

            Assert.AreEqual(expected, actual.Count);
        }
```

**Question 2**: In order to fix the issue above, I tried implementing an async function so I run my unit test without error. Unfortunately, now I'm only parsing a single iFrame on a page. How can I fix this?

```
private static async Task<IEnumerable<T>> GetAllFramesRecursive<T>(IWebElement frame, IWebDriver driver)
        {
            dynamic result = new Stack<IWebElement>();

            BaseIFrame baseClass = new BaseIFrame(driver);

            var iFrameList = baseClass._iframes;
            var iFrameCount = iFrameList.Count;

            foreach (var i in iFrameList)
            {
                result.Push(i);

                for (var j = 0; j < iFrameCount; j++)
                {
                    result.Push(j);
                    await GetAllFramesRecursive<T>(i, driver);
                }
            }

            return result;
        }

        // Public callable method for unit test
        public void GetAlliFramesRecursivePublic<T>(IWebElement test, IWebDriver driver)
        {
            GetAllFramesRecursive<IWebElement>(test, driver);
        }
```

The above code utilizes the same unit test posted. The end result is as follows:

`Assert.AreEqual failed. Expected:<24>. Actual:<1>.`

Comment: you'll probably need a webdriverwait for the findelements call, and to catch stale element exceptions to re-run if needed.  Recursion probably won't work unless you launch a new driver for each loop.  Why did you need that here?

Comment: Why did I use recursion? I wanted a function that calls itself on the source of every frame I find. I tried non-static methods without return statements and the farthest nested iFrame I could reach is two levels deep... but not enough to catch every iFrame on a page

Comment: I believe you'll need a new driver/thread for each level deep... you'll also need to wait for the frame(s) to be available.  There's an expected condition for that.  FrameToBeAvailableAndSwitchToIt.